# Choosing between very different presentation topics for PhD application

Tags: phd, application, interview

I have an interview for a theoretical physics PhD position next week. I have been requested to prepare a 10 minute presentation of some of my recent work for the interview. Herein lies my dilemma: my Masters thesis, which I am very proud of, contains original results and showcases my abilities well, but lies in a different field than the field that I have applied for (think hep-th vs cmt). Some theoretical skills may be transferable to this new position.

However, last summer, I performed research at a different lab in a similar field to the one I am applying for. The research was much less organized, a combination of various experimental and computational projects - not theoretical. One of those projects led to co-authorship on an upcoming publication, but I don't believe it showcases my abilities as well as my Masters thesis and I am a bit less familiar with the topic and slightly less confident in my methods. Since I only have 10 minutes, I assume that I should limit myself to one research project only. Which one should I chose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options. One is to choose the one you think best, maybe the first, but add a sentence or two at the end pointing out the other. Less than one minute here, though there may be questions after you finish.

The other is to ask whomever you are communicating with which they might rather see. Explain the options as you do here.

Good luck.